# How to calculate differential forms on $S^2$ parameterized by stereographic projection?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that we have the stereographic mapping $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2\to M$ where $M=S^2-\{(0,0,1)\}$.

I've already found that the stereographic parametrization of $S^2-\{(0,0,1)\}$ is given by:

$$(x,y) \mapsto (\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2},\dfrac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2},\dfrac{x^2+y^2-1}{1+x^2+y^2})$$

Normally, if I want to find a basis for $T_p(M)$, I can find $\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial y}$ and then consider the plane that is spanned by $<\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial y}>$ at each point $p$. I've already found these two vectors to be:

$$\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial x}=<\dfrac{2(1-x^2+y^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}, \dfrac{-4xy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}, \dfrac{4x}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}>$$

$$\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial y}=<\dfrac{-4xy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}, \dfrac{2(1+x^2-y^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}, \dfrac{4y}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}>$$

The vectors are orthogonal at all points and therefore create a basis for $T_p(M)$. The problem is that calculation with this basis looks very very hard, almost impossible to be done by hand.

Now the exercise asks me to show that the surface element on $M$, i.e. $dS$ is given by the differential form $\omega = x \space dy \wedge dz + y \space dz \wedge dx + z \space dx \wedge dy $.

Apparently, the surface element on $M$ at the point $p$ should be given by $\|\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial x} \times \dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial y} \|_p $. So I should show that when we input $<\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial{\varphi} }{\partial y}>$ into $w$ it gives the same result. Am I right?

But how can we do that? The calculations seem to be crazily hard. Even wolfram alpha couldn't do it. Is there another way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Using the stereographic coordinates for this problem is a trap, especially since the desired final answer is in the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates anyway. The easiest way to approach this problem is to remember that the metric on $S^2$ comes from the embedding $S^2 \to \mathbb R^3$.

For any isometric immersion like this we have (up to sign/after choosing orientations appropriately) the formula $dS = \iota_\nu dV$ where

- $dV$ is the volume form of $\mathbb R^3$
- $\nu$ is a smooth unit normal vector field to $S^2$
- $\iota$ is contraction/the interior product.

This formula should be somewhat intuitive: whenever you have an orthonormal basis for $T_pS^2$ you can add $\nu|_p$ to get an orthonormal basis for $T_p \mathbb R^3$.

In this case we can use $\nu = (x,y,z)$, and thus the linearity of $\iota$ gives

$$ dS = x\ \iota_{\partial_x} dV + y\ \iota_{\partial_y} dV + z\ \iota_{\partial_z} dV.$$

Now remember that $dV = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz = dy \wedge dz \wedge dx = dz \wedge dx \wedge dy$; so contracting $dV$ with $\partial_{x^i}$ just removes the $dx^i$. Thus

$$ dS = x\ dy \wedge dz + y\ dz \wedge dx + z\ dx \wedge dy $$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of have a vague idea about why your answer works, even though I don't know about immersions and metrics yet. Would you please expand your answer and explain what an isometric immersion is and how interior product is defined? The stereographic projection isn't an isometry, is that why it fails to give the right volume form on $S^2$?

Comment: @math.n00b: I'm surprised you're dealing with volume forms without first being taught about metrics. An isometric immersion is basically a differentiable inclusion map that preserves the geometry - so when you're defining the geometry on $S^2$ to be the restriction of the geometry on $\mathbb R^3$, the inclusion $S^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ is isometric by definition. The interior product is just "plugging a single vector in": for a form $\omega$, $\iota_X \omega$ is the form that sends $Y,Z,\ldots$ to $\omega(X,Y,Z,\ldots)$.

Comment: The stereographic coordinates as a map from the Euclidean plane to the sphere is not an isometry - if they were then $dx \wedge dy$ (the $x,y$ here from the plane, not the 3-space that the sphere is sitting inside) would be the area form of the sphere. You *could* compute the area form using the stereographic coordinates - the expression would indeed be the ugly $dS = \Vert \varphi _x \times \varphi_y \Vert dx\wedge dy$.